# Is it possible to filter by average group response in Tableau? (Survey Data)

Tags: tableau-api

I have a survey that was given across three departments, and I want to highlight where each department differed from the others on a given question.

I can display each department's average response to every question, but with 80 questions, that is a whole lot of bars! What I want to do is take the average response to a given question for each department, and if that average is more than .5 different from the overall average for that question, it displays the bar. Otherwise, it gets filtered out.

For example, let's say the question is "What is your overall satisfaction with puppies?" and the respondent can choose between 1 and 5.

Department 1's average response was 4.5
Department 2's average response was 3.5
Department 3's average response was 3.2

For that question, I only want to display the bar for Department 1.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Read about Level of Detail (LOD) calculations in the Tableau help. They are the right tool for this job.

Comment: It would be useful to have a sample dataset in the question. Thanks.